# How can I finish a hole in the wall?

Tags: drywall, trim, home-theater, projector

Considering a home theater "upgrade" for the house. When I was thinking about placement for the projector, I realized that the back wall of my living room is actually the wall to the Kitchen Pantry. Wife would not mind having a small rack for a projector in the pantry, and so I wanted to ask how you might go about having a hole in the wall with a glass optic to shine the projector through to the other room.

Through avsforums, I found that Edmunds non reflective glass would run me about $30-$40. However I'm concerned how I would finish up the hole, so that I don't end up having a literal hole in my wall!

Are there any ready to use items I could use to fashion a hole grommet/housing for the optic? (I was thinking a 3-4" diameter hole would be more than OK).

Considering this hole is going in the living room, it can't look too weird too. I welcome your suggestions!

UPDATE: In addition to the answers below, I found this product which is probably made for finishing a "hole": [http://www.amazon.com/FastCap-Dually-Double-Sided-Plastic-Grommet/dp/B007CI3XL6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007CI3XL6)

Also, cord grommets will work: [http://www.amazon.com/Black-Desk-Grommet-Pack/dp/B000MM7PXG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MM7PXG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a design and/or shopping question, that is completely dependent on personal preference. You could trim the hole out with wood, some type of metal or plastic flange, some type of port hole from a ship (if you're going for a nautical theme), etc.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The options are only limited by your imagination.

Comment: +1 If you search the web for images of *round flange*, you will find lots of possibilities. If you could get away with 2.5", high speed heating vents come in a wide variety of finishes. You also should consider using a short section of pipe (plastic or metal) lining the hole in the wall itself to reduce dust and airflow.

Comment: Amazing. I can't upvote because I don't have 15 rep yet, but you deserve it!

Comment: I found this, which could be used as well: http://www.fastcap.com/estore/pc/Dually-Grommet-p13445.htm

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't understand the problem.  If you are making a projection port, why would it look funny?
The standard professional projection window is fairly innocuous, even when used with a humongous projector:

[image]
(From http://neiloseman.com/?p=3222)

Here are two which are much larger than you might use for your application:

[image]
(From https://www.flickr.com/photos/yebot/4847816653/)

Certainly it would be easy to improve on the cosmetics.